# Error in prediction using sknn.mlp

Tags: python, windows, pyspark

I use Anaconda on a Windows 10 laptop with Python 2.7 and Spark 2.1. Built a deep learning model using Sknn.mlp package. I have completed the model. When I try to predict using the predict function, it throws an error. I run the same code on my Mac and it works just fine. Wondering what is wrong with my windows packages.

> 'NoneType' object is not callable

I verified input data. It is numpy.array and it does not have null value. Its dimension is same as training one and all attributed are the same. Not sure what it can be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Python on Windows, so this answer will be very vague, but maybe it will guide you in the right direction. Sometimes there are cross-platform errors due to one module still not being updated for the OS, frequently when another related module gets an update. I recall something happened to me with a django application which required somebody more familiar with Windows to fix it for me.

Maybe you could try with an environment using older versions of your modules until you find the culprit.

Comment: although your answer doesn't solve it..pointing in the right direction is always helpfull. As you got lacking rep this would normally be a comment only. Try posting a question yourself and get rep from that. Enjoy SO ;-).

Comment: Thanks Edwin. Hopefully someone would come up with the same experience to offer help or myself will post it if I found.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem on windows. Here is the solution in case you face it.

The Theano package was faulty. I installed the latest version from github and then it threw another error as below:

> RuntimeError: To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU" in your environment.

In order to solve this, I created a variable named MKL_Threading_Layer under user environment variable and passed GNU. Reset the kernel and it was working.

Hope it helps!